# What physical characteristics would be suited for android's OS to run smoothly?

Tags: android

Do you think a smartphone with this characteristics will be able to stand android OS?
 - 100 MB Storage 
 - -64 MB RAM
 - Processor  PNX-4910

////Edit--_

old version/ stable version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android 2.1+ requires at least 92MB of RAM.

See: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/source.android.com/en/us/compatibility/2.1/android-2.1-cdd.pdf

So your only hope would be a pre 2.1 version.

Theoretically, you might be able to get 1.6 or earlier to work on it, but the arm926 chip inside the PNX-4910 is not going to withstand a whole lot of load.

Comment: Any other OS that you would recommend that doesn't use .jar applications?

Comment: You could certainly get some version of Linux to run.

Comment: I think that arch Linux has pretty good support for the ARM platform. If you're trying to use telephony (the device sounds like a dumbphone), you're likely to run into problems getting Linux to work though.

Answer (score 1):

At most barely and unpleasently, based on limited ram if nothing else.

Comment: You see the OS the mobile does not support some applications, 
is there any other os you would recommend installing?